# How to define conversion to class template working when used as function argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, compile-time

Having this template:

```cpp
template <bool X> 
struct Foo {
  Foo(int v) : v(v) {}
  int v;
};
```

I can say that by default `Foo` should be of `False` with deduction guide:

```cpp
Foo(int)->Foo<false>;
```

Thank's to which this code works:

```cpp
Foo a = 5;
```

My problem is, how can i make this work when `Foo` is used as function argument:

```cpp
template <bool X> 
void f(Foo<X> foo) { 
  cout << "Foo<" << X << ">(" << foo.v << ")" << endl; 
}
```

```cpp
f(5); // error: no matching function for call to 'f'
      // candidate template ignored: could not match 'Foo<X>' against 'int'
```

I tried saying somehow `f` that `X` is by default `false` but `f` (I mean compiler) is not listening to me:

```cpp
template <bool X = false> // = false changes nothing, same error 
void f(Foo<X> foo) {
  cout << "Foo<" << X << ">(" << foo.v << ")" << endl; 
}
```

```cpp
template <bool X> 
struct get_bool { // to force looking at f::X 
  static constexpr bool value = X; 
};

template <bool X = false> 
void f(Foo<get_bool<X>::value> foo) { 
  cout << "Foo<" << X << ">(" << foo.v << ")" << endl;         
  /* this is not working because 
   * get_bool evaulates before 
   * args matching and in the end, 
   * this function could be defined 
   * as: void f(Foo<false>) 
   */
}
```

I don't mind introducing some additional helper classes etc. 
I was hoping that maybe some `decltype`, `auto`, `some_trait<>` or additional helper class (/es) magic could help here to solve this problem which I think I could also sum up as:
How to define a deduction guide for function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `template <bool X = false> void f(Foo<X> foo)` is that implicit conversions are not allowed when passing arguments to parameters that are used in template parameter deduction.

You can either add an extra overload of `f` accepting an `int`, or not make `f` a template at all:

```
struct Bar
{
    bool x = false;
    int v = 0;

    template <bool X>
    Bar(Foo<X> foo) : x(X), v(foo) {}

    Bar(int v) : v(v) {}
};

void f(Bar bar) {...}
```

It means the boolean is no longer `constexpr` inside of `f`. If you want it to be `constexpr`, there's a trick you can use:

```
void f(Bar bar)
{
    auto lambda = [&](auto x_value)
    {
        constexpr bool x = x_value;
        // Here `x` is `constexpr`.
    };

    if (bar.x)
        lambda(std::true_type{});
    else
        lambda(std::false_type{});
}
```

Comment: I wish that there would be some syntax to allow implicit conversions "when passing arguments to parameters that are used in template parameter deduction". Either way, this is helping a lot, thanks.